# To have a seperate DAO implementation class for each database table is a good approach?

Tags: java, database, dao

I have two table called `table_1` and `table_2`, and on each table I have to perform some insert, delete and update operation.

Can anyone please let me know that should I create two different (Data access object) implementation or should I have only one? and whats the advantage or disadvantage in both the approaches.

Answer (score 2):

If rows can be inserted/updated/deleted independently in both the tables then yes, you should go ahead with separate `DAO` classes. Below are the advantages:

- It promotes [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design pattern.
- [Spring data jpa](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) also uses the same design, it works on one `Repository` per entity (table in our case)
- If you have any functionality that requires querying both table 1 and table2 then it should ideally go into `service` layer and call two `DAO`s. Also, if you have any foreign key relationships between these tables, you can map it using `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany` etc annotations.